# Генерация класса из xsd

Tags: c#, xml

Столкнулся с XML-сериализацией/десериализацией. В основном все советуют использовать `xsd.exe` для генерации класса, но примеры в основном на "примитивных" схемах. Попробовал использовать на "сложной" схеме (complexType и тд) - сгенерировалось  немного не то, да и с "ошибками" (для поля для которого можно использовать `string` он генерирует отдельный класс и тд). 
Возник вопрос что лучше - писать в ручную классы или использовать другие инструменты или править уже сгенирированное? И как в основном поступают при профессиональной разработке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема одна: XML плохо соответствует модели данных современных языков. У элементов есть и атрибуты, и свойства — как их размещать и разделять в одном классе? Типы могут смешиваться самыми произвольными способами — как выразить это в языках, которые не имеют подобной выразительности?

Если вам нужно преобразовать сложный XML в объект в вашем любимом языке программирования, то пусть у вас один — боль и страдания. А именно написание кода вручную.

XSD.exe можно использовать, если нужно описать огромное количество типов, и хочется начать с чего-то более-менее соответствующего схеме, а не с нуля. В этом случае это будет заготовка.

XSD.exe можно использовать, если схема изначально писалась под этот инстурмент. Если сразу предполагать генерацию кода по схеме конкретным инструментом, то можно аккуратно вписаться в ограничения языка и инструмента. Но предупреждаю: это всё равно путь боли и страданий. Скорее всего, вас будут жутко раздражать ограничения, накладываемые XSD.exe, потому что это довольно грубый инструмент.

При желании к XSD.exe можно накрутить костылей. Этот инструмент — не более, чем консольная обёртка над `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlCodeExporter`.

Если вы хотите получать удовольствие от написания кода, то опишите классы изначально в коде, а сериализуйте чем душе угодно.

К сожалению, этот способ доступен, только если это вы генерируете XML, а не вам приходится потреблять сгенерированный кем-то другим XML. В такой безвыходной ситуации можете подобрать генератор кода помощнее. См. [Comparison of XSD Code Generators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/386155).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, а не могли бы вы рассказать поподробнее про ситуацию, когда приходится потреблять сгенерированный кем-то другим XML? Какие профессиональные подходы в этом случае?

Comment: @e1s Ну какой профессиональный подход... страдать. :) Красиво и универсально эта задача не решается. Пробуете все генераторы подряд — авось какой-то вас удовлетворит. Если ни один не удовлетворит, то придётся выбирать между автогенерацией паршивого кода и ручным написанием чистого кода. Ну или можете взять `XmlCodeExporter`, например, и в вручную латать CodeDom. XSD разные бывают: некоторые красиво ложатся на код, некоторые при всём желании кроме как вручную не обработаешь (XSD не может выразить всё, что придумали сгенерировавшие XML).

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то xsd используется для валидации xml?

Comment: @e1s Э... генерация XSD и кода, конвертация. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx